# Dropdownbutton Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, dropdownbutton

I created a dropdownbutton, after i chose something the area is grey. Is it possible to get it away?
I don´t know if  theres an property to do it, but can´t find one yet.

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
Container(
                      child: const Text('Multiplechoice?',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 10.0, 0),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 15.0)),
                  Container(
                    width: 300,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 8, vertical: 2),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
                    ),
                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                        child: DropdownButton<DropdownOption>(
                      value: service.getSeventhOption,
                      isExpanded: true,
                      hint: const Text('Please choose'),
                      style: Constants.questionStyle,
                      iconSize: 20,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          color: Colors.black),
                      onChanged: (DropdownOption? newValue) {
                        service.setSeventhOption = newValue!;
                      },
                      items: service.seventhDropdown
                          .map((DropdownOption option) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<DropdownOption>(
                          value: option,
                          child: Text(option.text!),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    )),
                  ),,
```

Comment: please add your code

Comment: pardon, i forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grey area indicates that your `DropdownButton` is currently focused. After selecting a `value` in your `DropdownButton`, the focus remains on it. This is the reason why it is grey. If you focus something else e.g. a button or on the screen, they grey color will disappear, since it isn't on focus anymore.
If you want to change the color of the grey area, you can set the [focusColor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/focusColor.html).

```
DropdownButton<DropdownOption>(
  focusColor: Colors.transparent,
  ...
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
///you can try this way I created my dropdown like this. hope this will work for you

  var _currentSelectedValue;
  var _currencies = [
    "Train",
    "Flight",
    "Car",
    "Dinner",
    "BreakFast",
    "Lunch",
    "Accommodation",
    "Mileage Allowance",
  ];



 FormField<String>(
                                builder: (FormFieldState<String> state) {
                                  return Container(
                                    width: _width! * 0.90,
                                    child: InputDecorator(
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        contentPadding:
                                            EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 15),
                                        /*contentPadding:
                                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),*/
                                        isDense: true,
                                        errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.redAccent,
                                            fontSize: 16.0),
                                        hintText: 'Please select expense',
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),
                                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.textFieldColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                                            color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      isEmpty: _currentSelectedValue == '',
                                      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                        child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.arrow_drop_down_sharp,
                                            color: AppColors.baseLightBlueColor,
                                          ),
                                          hint: Text(
                                            'Please select expense',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: AppColors.hotelListDarkBlue),
                                          ),
                                          value: _currentSelectedValue,
                                          isDense: true,
                                          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _currentSelectedValue = newValue;
                                              state.didChange(newValue);
                                            });
                                          },
                                          items: _currencies.map((String value) {
                                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: Text(value),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
```